# Using SherlockFragmentActivity works in newer android phone but not older model

Tags: android, tabs, swipeview

so I have tested this code on a newer android and when I test it on an older version and click on a button to take me to a page with SwipeView and tabs, I get an error:

The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

I have set the minimumSDK level in the android manifest to 7. I'm not sure why it won't work on the older android phone.

Here's my code for the SwipeView class:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SwipeMode extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

    DemoCollectionPagerAdapter mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.swipemode);

        mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter = new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home button should show an "Up" caret, indicating that touching the
        // button will take the user one step up in the application's hierarchy.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

     // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This is called when the Home (Up) button is pressed in the action bar.
                // Create a simple intent that starts the hierarchical parent activity and
                // use NavUtils in the Support Package to ensure proper handling of Up.
                Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                    // This activity is not part of the application's task, so create a new task
                    // with a synthesized back stack.
                    TaskStackBuilder.from(this)
                            // If there are ancestor activities, they should be added here.
                            .addNextIntent(upIntent)
                            .startActivities();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // This activity is part of the application's task, so simply
                    // navigate up to the hierarchical parent activity.
                    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public static class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        //unimplemented methods were automatically added
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1); // Our object is just an integer :-P
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        //number of pages
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
        }
    }
    public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_object, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            //This part sets the integer to string text on the layouts
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                    Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: How old is your older Android? What is the exact exception message and stack trace from log cat? ActionBarSherlock works with Android 2.x and higher so the minimum API level should be 5. If your Android device is older then it won't work

Comment: 08-19 15:16:35.801: I/dalvikvm(2847): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.setTranslationX

Comment: Also, the phone is the HTC G2

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. 
`getActionBar()` is supported from API lvl 11+